# ImageResizer slow performance

Tags: imageresizer

I download the files and added them to my ***ASP.Net MVC app***.
Using Image object, loading and converting a one page `tiff` into a `gif` (into a memory stream) took approx ***180ms***. I converted the code to call ImageResizer and it took ***360ms*** for the same functionality.
What am I doing wrong?

*NOTE!* Removing the PrettyGifs plug-in from the config did not change the times.

```
ImageResizer.Configuration.Config c = new ImageResizer.Configuration.Config(new ResizerSection("<resizer><plugins><add name=\"PrettyGifs\"/></plugins></resizer>"));
c.Plugins.LoadPlugins();
string s = c.GetDiagnosticsPage();

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
c.BuildImage(sPath, ms, "format=gif");
// ...
}

debug dump follows:

Diagnostics for ImageResizer 4.1.9 008a626e at localhost generated 11/22/2017 5:57:58 PM
Please remember to provide this page when contacting support.


You are using ImageResizer Essential Edition plugins.

3 issues detected:

Plugins(ConfigurationError):    Failed to load plugin by name "(PrettyGifs, )"
            Verify that "ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs"  is located in /bin. 
            Attempted using "(PrettyGifs, )", "ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs.PrettyGifs, ImageResizer.Plugins.PrettyGifs".

(Warning):  To potentially see additional errors here, perform an image resize request.


(Warning):  NoCache is only for development usage, and cannot scale to production use.
            Add DiskCache or CloudFront for production use




Configuration:

<resizer>
<plugins>
<add name="PrettyGifs" />
</plugins>
</resizer>


Registered plugins:

ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.DefaultEncoder
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.NoCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.ClientCache
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.WebConfigLicenseReader
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.Diagnostic
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.SizeLimiting
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.MvcRoutingShimPlugin
ImageResizer.Plugins.Basic.LicenseDisplay

Accepted querystring keys:

quality, format, thumbnail, maxwidth, maxheight, width, height, w, h, crop, page, bgcolor, rotate, flip, sourceFlip, sFlip, sRotate, borderWidth, borderColor, paddingWidth, paddingColor, frame, useresizingpipeline, cache, process, margin, dpi, zoom, autorotate

Accepted file extensions:

bmp, gif, exif, png, tif, tiff, tff, jpg, jpeg, jpe, jif, jfif, jfi

Environment information:

Running Microsoft-IIS/7.5 on Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 and CLR 4.0.30319.42000
Trust level: Unrestricted
OS bitness: x86 !! Warning, running as 32-bit on a 64-bit OS(AMD64). This will limit ram usage !!
Executing assembly: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
IntegratedPipeline: True

Installed HttpModules: 

System.Web.Caching.OutputCacheModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key OutputCache)
System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key Session)
System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key WindowsAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key DefaultAuthentication)
System.Web.Security.RoleManagerModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key RoleManager)
System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key UrlAuthorization)
System.Web.Security.FileAuthorizationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key FileAuthorization)
System.Web.Security.AnonymousIdentificationModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key AnonymousIdentification)
System.Web.Profile.ProfileModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key Profile)
System.Web.UrlMappingsModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key UrlMappingsModule)
System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key ServiceModel-4.0)
System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key UrlRoutingModule-4.0)
System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key ScriptModule-4.0)
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key __DynamicModule_Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_4b61d1fe-9d0d-40fa-8758-849993d10ed8)
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.PageInspectorHttpModule, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a          (under key __DynamicModule_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.PageInspectorHttpModule, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a_b766f75d-dc9c-446d-b9d4-27754073ec64)
System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule, System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key __DynamicModule_System.Web.WebPages.WebPageHttpModule, System.Web.WebPages, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_a7f2b575-ca4b-4063-b1b3-d707ed457563)
System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule, System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35          (under key __DynamicModule_System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule, System.Web.Optimization, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35_8481b6cf-51ab-49c8-8764-35a90d302db4)
WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager+StartMethodCallingModule, WebActivatorEx, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7b26dc2a43f6a0d4          (under key __DynamicModule_WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager+StartMethodCallingModule, WebActivatorEx, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7b26dc2a43f6a0d4_c775403c-b69b-4620-b175-1631096b7541)

Loaded assemblies:

mscorlib                                 File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Web                               File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System                                   File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Core                              File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Web.ApplicationServices           File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Configuration                     File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Xml                               File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Runtime.Caching                   File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0           File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
Microsoft.JScript                        File: 14.0.1099.0 (10.0.0.0)    Informational: 14.0.1099.0                    
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader File: 15.0.30223.0 (1.0.0.0)    Informational: 15.0.30223.0.Release.b364      
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           File: 2.0.20710.0 (2.0.0.0)     Informational:                                
Microsoft.CSharp                         File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Data                              File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Web.Services                      File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Drawing                           File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.EnterpriseServices                File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.IdentityModel                     File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Runtime.Serialization             File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.ServiceModel                      File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.ServiceModel.Activation           File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.ServiceModel.Web                  File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Activities                        File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.ServiceModel.Activities           File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.WorkflowServices                  File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Web.Extensions                    File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Data.DataSetExtensions            File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Xml.Linq                          File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations    File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Web.DynamicData                   File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
ABCpdf                                   File:  (10.1.0.6)               Informational:                                
Antlr3.Runtime                           File: 3.4.1.9004 (3.4.1.9004)   Informational:                                
AutoMapper                               File: 3.3.1 (3.3.1.0)           Informational: bdf5b3a6393466ff15cbdb082b9d1b01f277f4dd  
AutoMapper.Net4                          File: 3.3.1 (3.3.1.0)           Informational: bdf5b3a6393466ff15cbdb082b9d1b01f277f4dd  
DMAccess                                 File: 1.0.0.0 (1.0.0.0)         Informational:                                
DMAccess4                                File: 1.0.0.0 (1.0.0.0)         Informational:                                
ImageResizer                             File: 4.1.9.1086 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.1.9 008a626e                 
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core           File: 2.1.30612.0 (2.0.0.0)     Informational:                                
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin           File: 2.1.30612.0 (2.0.0.0)     Informational:                                
Microsoft.Owin                           File: 2.1.30113.529 (2.1.0.0)   Informational: 2.1.0                          
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb            File: 2.1.30113.529 (2.1.0.0)   Informational: 2.1.0                          
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies          File: 2.1.30113.529 (2.1.0.0)   Informational: 2.1.0                          
Microsoft.Owin.Security                  File: 2.1.30113.529 (2.1.0.0)   Informational: 2.1.0                          
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook         File: 2.1.30113.529 (2.1.0.0)   Informational: 2.1.0                          
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google           File: 2.1.30113.529 (2.1.0.0)   Informational: 2.1.0                          
Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount File: 2.1.30113.529 (2.1.0.0)   Informational: 2.1.0                          
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth            File: 2.1.30113.529 (2.1.0.0)   Informational: 2.1.0                          
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter          File: 2.1.30113.529 (2.1.0.0)   Informational: 2.1.0                          
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation      File: 1.2.0.0 (1.2.0.0)         Informational:                                
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration  File: 3.5.1404.0 (3.5.0.0)      Informational: 3.5.1404.0                     
Microsoft.Practices.Unity                File: 3.5.1404.0 (3.5.0.0)      Informational: 3.5.1404.0                     
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Mvc            File: 3.5.1404.0 (3.5.0.0)      Informational: 3.5.1404.0                     
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.RegistrationByConvention File: 3.5.1404.0 (3.5.0.0)      Informational: 3.5.1404.0                     
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure             File: 1.0.20105.407 (1.0.0.0)   Informational:                                
Newtonsoft.Json                          File: 10.0.2.20802 (10.0.0.0)   Informational:                                
Owin                                     File: 1.0 (1.0.0.0)             Informational:                                
System.Net.Http.Formatting               File: 5.2.20627.0 (5.2.0.0)     Informational: 5.2.0-20627 (0adbfd47c58682f25b5ace9732ca9374ed1f9a89)  
System.Web.Helpers                       File: 3.0.20627.0 (3.0.0.0)     Informational: 3.0.0-20627 (0adbfd47c58682f25b5ace9732ca9374ed1f9a89)  
System.Web.Http                          File: 5.2.20627.0 (5.2.0.0)     Informational: 5.2.0-20627 (0adbfd47c58682f25b5ace9732ca9374ed1f9a89)  
System.Web.Http.WebHost                  File: 5.2.20627.0 (5.2.0.0)     Informational: 5.2.0-20627 (0adbfd47c58682f25b5ace9732ca9374ed1f9a89)  
System.Web.Mvc                           File: 5.2.20627.0 (5.2.0.0)     Informational: 5.2.0-20627 (0adbfd47c58682f25b5ace9732ca9374ed1f9a89)  
System.Web.Optimization                  File: 1.1.40211.0 (1.1.0.0)     Informational:                                
System.Web.Razor                         File: 3.0.20627.0 (3.0.0.0)     Informational: 3.0.0-20627 (0adbfd47c58682f25b5ace9732ca9374ed1f9a89)  
System.Web.WebPages.Deployment           File: 3.0.20627.0 (3.0.0.0)     Informational: 3.0.0-20627 (0adbfd47c58682f25b5ace9732ca9374ed1f9a89)  
System.Web.WebPages                      File: 3.0.20627.0 (3.0.0.0)     Informational: 3.0.0-20627 (0adbfd47c58682f25b5ace9732ca9374ed1f9a89)  
System.Web.WebPages.Razor                File: 3.0.20627.0 (3.0.0.0)     Informational: 3.0.0-20627 (0adbfd47c58682f25b5ace9732ca9374ed1f9a89)  
Viewer                                   File: 2.1.1.59 (2.1.1.59)       Informational:                                
WebActivatorEx                           File: 2.0.0 (2.0.0.0)           Informational:                                
WebGrease                                File:  (1.5.2.14234)            Informational:                                
WVLDataDBInfo                            File: 1.0.0.0 (1.0.0.0)         Informational:                                
WVLDataFunction_VS2013                   File: 1.0.0.0 (1.0.0.0)         Informational:                                
WVLDataSelect_VS2013                     File: 1.0.0.0 (1.0.0.0)         Informational:                                
WVLDataTables_VS2013                     File: 1.0.0.0 (1.0.0.0)         Informational:                                
WVLDataUpdate_VS2013                     File: 1.0.0.0 (1.0.0.0)         Informational:                                
WVLUtility_VS2013                        File: 1.0.0.0 (1.0.0.0)         Informational:                                
System.Xaml                              File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Runtime                           File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Resources.ResourceManager         File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime File: 15.0.30223.0 (15.0.0.0)   Informational: 15.0.30223.0.Release.b364      
System.Threading                         File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Collections                       File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Reflection                        File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Linq                              File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Globalization                     File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Runtime.Extensions                File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing File: 15.0.30223.0 (15.0.0.0)   Informational: 15.0.30223.0.Release.b364      
System.Web.RegularExpressions            File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Data.Services.Design              File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
App_global.asax.ggunmg-i                 File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
System.Net.Http                          File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Security                          File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Workflow.Runtime                  File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Workflow.ComponentModel           File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Workflow.Activities               File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Windows.Forms                     File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.ServiceModel.Internals            File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
Microsoft.Build.Framework                File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Transactions                      File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Runtime.DurableInstancing         File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
SMDiagnostics                            File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
System.Data.SqlXml                       File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
WindowsBase                              File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.7.2117.0                     
PresentationCore                         File: 4.7.2117.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.0.30319.0                    
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler File: 14.0.1099.0 (10.0.0.0)    Informational: 14.0.1099.0                    
System.Xaml.Hosting                      File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Web.DataVisualization             File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Linq.Expressions                  File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Data.Linq                         File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
System.Reflection.Extensions             File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Web.Mobile                        File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
System.Numerics                          File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
App_Web_jndr5day                         File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
App_Web_lqt1vnua                         File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                
System.Dynamic                           File: 4.6.1099.0 (4.0.0.0)      Informational: 4.6.1099.0                     
App_Web_jfekiwfs                         File:  (0.0.0.0)                Informational:                                



When fetching a remote license file (if you have one), the following information is sent via the querystring.
                         license_id [integer]
                         manager_id [guid]
                   total_heartbeats [integer]
                     new_heartbeats [integer]
                    first_heartbeat [integer]
                  reporting_version 3
                            proc_64 0
                          proc_guid k1hE2f1IXU6qFozXmFa5cA
                    proc_sys_dotnet 4.6.1
                           proc_iis 7.5
           proc_integrated_pipeline 1
                   proc_asyncmodule 0
              proc_default_commands 
                proc_working_set_mb 200
                    proc_git_commit 008a626e
                  proc_info_version 4.1.9
                  proc_file_version 4.1.9.1086
                  proc_apppath_hash XPG0IWtk
                                mod .Caching.OutputCacheModule
                                mod .SessionState.SessionStateModule
                                mod .WindowsAuthenticationModule
                                mod .DefaultAuthenticationModule
                                mod .RoleManagerModule
                                mod .UrlAuthorizationModule
                                mod .FileAuthorizationModule
                                mod .AnonymousIdentificationModule
                                mod .Profile.ProfileModule
                                mod .UrlMappingsModule
                                mod System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule
                                mod .Routing.UrlRoutingModule
                                mod .Handlers.ScriptModule
                                mod Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpModule
                                mod Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.PageInspectorHttpModule
                                mod .WebPages.WebPageHttpModule
                                mod .Optimization.BundleModule
                                mod WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager+StartMethodCallingModule
                    h_logical_cores 8
                       h_mac_digest K7zlXaDggvePlww5J_7jnA
                             h_os64 1
             h_network_drives_count 0
               h_other_drives_count 1
               h_fixed_drives_count 3
                      h_fixed_drive NTFS*,6,246
                      h_fixed_drive NTFS,143,1000
                      h_fixed_drive NTFS,0,9
                                  p SizeLimiting
              counter_update_failed 0
               encoded_pixels_total 0
      encoded_pixels_per_second_max 0
      encoded_pixels_per_minute_max 0
     encoded_pixels_per_15_mins_max 0
        encoded_pixels_per_hour_max 0
               jobs_completed_total 0
      jobs_completed_per_second_max 0
      jobs_completed_per_minute_max 0
     jobs_completed_per_15_mins_max 0
        jobs_completed_per_hour_max 0
               decoded_pixels_total 0
      decoded_pixels_per_second_max 0
      decoded_pixels_per_minute_max 0
     decoded_pixels_per_15_mins_max 0
        decoded_pixels_per_hour_max 0
              blob_read_bytes_total 0
     blob_read_bytes_per_second_max 0
     blob_read_bytes_per_minute_max 0
    blob_read_bytes_per_15_mins_max 0
       blob_read_bytes_per_hour_max 0
                   blob_reads_total 0
          blob_reads_per_second_max 0
          blob_reads_per_minute_max 0
         blob_reads_per_15_mins_max 0
            blob_reads_per_hour_max 0
                   output_width_5th 0
                  output_width_25th 0
                  output_width_50th 0
                  output_width_75th 0
                  output_width_95th 0
                 output_width_100th 0
                      job_times_5th 0
                     job_times_25th 0
                     job_times_50th 0
                     job_times_75th 0
                     job_times_95th 0
                    job_times_100th 0
                blob_read_times_5th 0
               blob_read_times_25th 0
               blob_read_times_50th 0
               blob_read_times_75th 0
               blob_read_times_95th 0
              blob_read_times_100th 0
                 job_other_time_5th 0
                job_other_time_25th 0
                job_other_time_50th 0
                job_other_time_75th 0
                job_other_time_95th 0
               job_other_time_100th 0
            source_aspect_ratio_5th 0
           source_aspect_ratio_25th 0
           source_aspect_ratio_50th 0
           source_aspect_ratio_75th 0
           source_aspect_ratio_95th 0
          source_aspect_ratio_100th 0
                  output_height_5th 0
                 output_height_25th 0
                 output_height_50th 0
                 output_height_75th 0
                 output_height_95th 0
                output_height_100th 0
                  output_pixels_5th 0
                 output_pixels_25th 0
                 output_pixels_50th 0
                 output_pixels_75th 0
                 output_pixels_95th 0
                output_pixels_100th 0
                  scaling_ratio_5th 0
                 scaling_ratio_25th 0
                 scaling_ratio_50th 0
                 scaling_ratio_75th 0
                 scaling_ratio_95th 0
                scaling_ratio_100th 0
                   encode_times_5th 0
                  encode_times_25th 0
                  encode_times_50th 0
                  encode_times_75th 0
                  encode_times_95th 0
                 encode_times_100th 0
                   source_width_5th 0
                  source_width_25th 0
                  source_width_50th 0
                  source_width_75th 0
                  source_width_95th 0
                 source_width_100th 0
                  source_pixels_5th 0
                 source_pixels_25th 0
                 source_pixels_50th 0
                 source_pixels_75th 0
                 source_pixels_95th 0
                source_pixels_100th 0
                   decode_times_5th 0
                  decode_times_25th 0
                  decode_times_50th 0
                  decode_times_75th 0
                  decode_times_95th 0
                 decode_times_100th 0
                  source_height_5th 0
                 source_height_25th 0
                 source_height_50th 0
                 source_height_75th 0
                 source_height_95th 0
                source_height_100th 0
             collect_info_times_5th 0
            collect_info_times_25th 0
            collect_info_times_50th 0
            collect_info_times_75th 0
            collect_info_times_95th 0
           collect_info_times_100th 0
            output_aspect_ratio_5th 0
           output_aspect_ratio_25th 0
           output_aspect_ratio_50th 0
           output_aspect_ratio_75th 0
           output_aspect_ratio_95th 0
          output_aspect_ratio_100th 0
                      image_domains 
                       page_domains 
                         query_keys 
               extra_job_query_keys
```

Comment: Is this by any chance a black-and-white high-resolution image? ImageResizer 4 is not optimized for TIFF->GIF conversion. Imageflow is quite a bit faster.

Comment: black and white - yes

Comment: 200 dpi  - if not tiff to gif, is there a better image format  (IOW, one that con be converted to faster) that is supported  on "all" browsers

Comment: I assume from the lack of response that ImageResizer is not going to help my performance and I should look elsewhere or can I get assistance in making this a useful addition to our product?

Comment: ImageFlow appears incomplete and not updated recently.  How do I try it?  What is its status?